# Prevent reloading parent controller in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with nested views in ui-router.

My layout is :

```
site.search
-----------------
site.search.runs
-----------------
site.search.runs.scheme
-----------------
site.search.runs.scheme.payment
-----------------
```

I don't want to change url that's why I use `$state.go('', {}, {location:false});`
 I also use `$stage.go('^'...)` for back to parent.

But when I click on Back button on site.search.runs.scheme.payment or site.search.runs.scheme - site.runs controller also reloads (I don't use {reload:true}).
 How to prevent reloading top level parent controller ?
 I have found a problem like mine https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2096
 Can anybody help me ?

My configuration is

```
$stateProvider
        .state('site', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            template: '<ui-view/>'
        })
        .state('site.search', {
            url: '',
            parent: 'site',
            controller: 'SearchController',
            controllerAs: 'search',
            templateUrl: 'js/search/search.tpl.html'
        })
        .state('site.search.runs', {
            url: '',
            parent: 'site.search',
            params: {back: false, timestamp: 0, search: {}},
            controller: 'RunsController as runsCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'js/runs/runs.tpl.html'
        })
        .state('site.search.runs.scheme', {
            url: '',
            parent: 'site.search.runs',
            params: {back: false, run: ''},
            controller: 'SchemeController as schemeCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'js/scheme/scheme.tpl.html'
        })
        .state('site.search.runs.scheme.payment', {
            url: '',
            parent: 'site.search.runs.scheme',
            params: {back: false},
            controller: 'PaymentController as payCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'js/payment/liqpay/payment.tpl.html'
        })
});
```

Back method calls this  $state.go('^', {back: true}, {location: false, inherit: false});

Comment: This is not possible, since you are replacing the `ui-view` contents in each new state. Every time that happens, the view and controllers are destroyed/reinstantiated.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

A dirty trick you could do is wrap the controller code in an if statement and do something like this (this is by no means the best way, but it will certainly work):

```
// make sure you inject $state
// and put the if statement inside the main function of your controller

function RunsController($state) {
    // var will return something like: site.search.runs.scheme
    var currentState = $state.current.name;

    if (currentState === 'site.search.runs') {
        // in here put the code that would normally be in this controller for site.search.runs
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when you are calling $state.go().

You could try the notify: false flag on the back method `$state.go('^', {back: true}, {location: false, inherit: false, notify: false});`

If youre trying to call state.go in the middle of a state already in transition, you should try $state.transitionTo() for example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    $state.transitionTo('login');
}
```

I've found that transitionTo will not reload my parent controllers

```
$state.transitionTo('^', $stateParams, {
            reload: false, inherit: false, notify: false
        });
```

The parent property on the state is redundant if youre using dot notation so that could be causing a problem as only one is required. I would check $state.$current when youre calling 'back' to make sure you really are part of the parent's children.